# Can a half-elf with elven atavism take ethnicity feats?

Tags: pathfinder-2e

There are some feats & options that have an ethnicity requirement would a half elf with elven atavism decended from that ethnicity & raised in that culture of elves qualify.

Answer (score 10):

### Heritages Are Not Ethnicities

> A [heritage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=128) is not the same as a culture
> or ethnicity, though some cultures or ethnicities might
> have more or fewer members from a particular heritage.

Whether a half-elf (or Aiuvarin post-remaster) has an elven heritage through [Elf Atavism](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=79) or not doesn't inherently determine their ethnicity. Any half-elf belonging to the appropriate cultural group would qualify as a member of that ethnicity, without needing to take a feat for it.

For example, a Mualijae half-elf of the Mwangi Jungle could take [Share Thoughts](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=977) as their 1st-level ancestry feat, just like any other Half-Elf, Human, or Elf feat they qualify for.